# Kotlin KSP generated source not found during CI build

Tags: android, koin, kotlin-symbol-processing

I have a problem with KSP source code generation only during CI build event. It always work in my local machine. This is the [link](https://app.travis-ci.com/github/mirjalal/Structure/builds/256133894#L9968) to the error for travis build. What is the mistake in my config or source files here? This is the [link](https://github.com/mirjalal/Structure) to github repo.

I have added necessary rules from this [official demo app](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin-annotations/tree/main/quickstart/quickstart-android-annotations).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is hardly related to the KSP itself.

You error seems to be in `App.kt`

```
e: /home/travis/build/mirjalal/Structure/app/src/main/kotlin/az/talmir/app/structure/App.kt: (18, 39): Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public val KoinKernelModule.module: Module defined in org.koin.ksp.generated
```